# How to find a list of all nodes in a p2pool network?

Tags: p2pool, nodes

I'm running a [p2pool node](http://q30.qhor.net:8336/static/) for [cachecoin](http://cachecoin.org/) and see there are more users and hashrate in the overall p2pool network than from the known nodes.

Is there a way to get a list of the connected nodes somehow, maybe by IP?

All I see currently is the web frontend and the stdout buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is [p2pool-scanner](https://github.com/litecoin-project/p2pool-scanner).

A little piece of javascript with minimal webserver (NodeJS) which keeps scanning your local p2pool-data directory for node ips and scans all nodes for public html frontend. If it finds a public accessable frontend, it will add it to a list of public nodes and displays the results sorted by uptime.

Its easy modified (`scanner.cfg`) to work with any *coins p2pool network.

Here is an example node scanner for vertcoin: http://q30.qhor.net:9172/